# Restoring /etc/ssh/sshd_config to original Debian 9

Tags: debian, ssh

I forgot to make a backup of /etc/ssh/sshd_config when last editing it. I now want to restore it to the default. Can someone upload the original text or show me how to obtain the original myself if there is a way *should be right?*?

Thank you :)

Comment: sudo dpkg —reconfigure ssh maybe? Or apt-get install —reinstall ssh (https://superuser.com/a/102465 ).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TLDR: Check `/usr/share/openssh/sshd_config`.

Suggestion for the future: Look in to `etckeeper`.

Other than purging and re-installing a package, there isn't a general way on Debian to reset the config to the default. There are basically three different ways packages handle config:

1. Ship the configuration in the .deb as a dpkg config file. You could use `dpkg-deb -x` to extract this from the `.deb` file (do not extract to `/`! Instead extract it to a temporary directory, then copy it out). May archive managers can also extract from deb files for you.
2. Ship something that is basically the config somewhere other than `/etc` (often `/usr/share`), use `ucf` to install it.
3. Completely generate the config using scripts and install it somehow, often with `ucf`. If you're lucky, the generated file is sitting somewhere, probably in `/var/lib`.

As a user, you can tell them apart by what the you've modified the config prompt you sometimes see at upgrade looks like. `dpkg -S` will also only find files that are case #1 above.

Sometimes with (2) or (3), you'll get prompted again by using `dpkg --reconfigure «package»`, especially if you pick different options than before. But not always; depends on the package. (Ideally it'd never happen, but some config files are too complicated to easily merge in your changes).

openssh-server does (2); you can find the original config at `/usr/share/openssh/sshd_config`

Comment: Ahh, doi. Purging it would obviously reset it. I'm an idiot, haha.

But also those other options are helpful and I will keep them in mind. thanks :).